# rad date picker should load start date of current month automatically, when Page loads in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-raddatepicker

current month
current year
and start date(1 to be constant) in telerik rad date picker
Am working to get date 1= year,6 months back, 1
date2=year, current month, 1

i can get current date as below

```
    startdatepicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
//startdatepicker.SelectedDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6), 1);//-->this not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by:

```
DateTime end = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
enddate.SelectedDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

start.SelectedDate = (end.AddMonths(-6));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, unless I misunderstand your question...

startdatepicker.SelectedDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

Comment: Thank you @seano666

Comment: @seano666---> DtPickerEndDatee.SelectedDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6), 1);<-----

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6) is not a valid value for the month.

Comment: DtPickerEndDatee.SelectedDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6), 1);-----I tried as this, it's not working\

Comment: Cannot convert system.datetime to int --error under addmonths @seano666

Comment: There are several problems here.  You are trying to pass a DateTime object for an int parameter, and also what if subtracting 6 months takes you back to next year?  In that case, you do not want to use the current year in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, that a good point. How to show like date 1= 6 months back date 1

Comment: date 2 = current month date 1 @Seano666

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question, it's confusing what you are trying to do.